# Why change the IPv4 default broadcast address of a particular network?

Tags: networking, ipv4, broadcast

Some operating systems allow the user to change the broadcast address of a network, e.g. in Linux this can be done by using the SIOCSIFBRDADDR ioctl.

Why is this necessary? In which scenario would an admin not want to use the default broadcast address of her/his network?

Comment: There is no default broadcast address. The broadcast address depends on your network configuration. See [Default IP Routers, Network Masks, and Broadcast Addresses](https://www.net.princeton.edu/iprouters.html)

Comment: I edited the question to emphasize I'm talking about the default broadcast address of a particular network